# Creating an accordion in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an accordion using the following jQuery:

```
 var allPanels = $('.accordion > div.showlist > p.showdetails').hide();

  $('.accordion > div.showlist > strong').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
 <div class="showlist">
  <div class="showdate">date</div>
  <strong>The title</strong>
  <p class="showdetails">There is more info in here about the show here.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="showlist">
  <div class="showdate">date</div>
  <strong>The title</strong>
  <p class="showdetails">There is more info in here about the show here.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="showlist">
  <div class="showdate">date</div>
  <strong>The title</strong>
  <p class="showdetails">There is more info in here about the show here.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

The `p.showdetails` are being hidden fine, but when `strong` is clicked nothing happens. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use the Accordion plugin? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I am trying to learn jquery

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting the wrong things.

If your `click` event is on `<strong>`, then `$(this).parent().next()` will select the `div.showlist` next to it's parent `div.showlist` (whew!).

Just `$(this).next('p.showdetails').slideDown();` should work fine.

#### EDIT

Since you're using animations as well, calling `allPanels.slideUp()` before the `.slideDown()` call will *queue* the animations, so it'll look like the panel is sliding down and up *if you click the `<strong>` element of the currently visible `p.showdetails`.*

You should do something like

```
var panel = $(this).next('p.showdetails').slideDown();
allPanels.not(panel).slideUp();
```

... or something similar to prevent that.

Ooooooooooooooor you could work with the jQueryUI Accordion plugin. Nice on you to be doing this as an exercise though.

Comment: I tried changing to $(this).next('p.showdetails').slideDown(); but still nothing is happening

Comment: .next() only works for sibling elements, so $(this).next('p.showdetails') won't find anything

Comment: But the `<strong></strong>` and `<p class="showdetails"></p>` tags in his code are siblings, aren't they?

Comment: @user1444027 ~ Then there's something else wrong with your code that you're not showing us; I've plugged in your exact markup with my solution, and it's working here: http://jsbin.com/owaxus/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't `$(this).parent().next()` return the next `div.showlist`? I think what you want is:

```
$(".showdetails", $(this).parent().next()).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**

I did some work around and came up with this one.

You need to use

```
 $(".showdetails", $(this).parent()).slideDown();
```

I have done a sample in jsfiddle you can refer that.

http://jsfiddle.net/nS84p/3/

***Optional***

> You can opt for jQuery accordian which is easy and user friendly
>
> [Refer This URL For Information](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Jus some minutes difference between our answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with:

```
$(".showdetails", $(this).parent()).slideDown();
```

Thanks for the help everyone.